# How to Ignore specific file from Visual Studio Warnings Analyzer?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there any way to suppress all error codes in one specific file?

> Surprisingly I couldn't find this. This is pretty common scenario
> isn't it?

Documentation describes it seems:

1. we have to disable it line by line or
2. globally across all files.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/in-source-suppression-overview?view=vs-2022#:~:text=You%20can%20suppress%20violations%20in,can%20use%20the%20SuppressMessage%20attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/in-source-suppression-overview?view=vs-2022#:%7E:text=You%20can%20suppress%20violations%20in,can%20use%20the%20SuppressMessage%20attribute).

Comment: Compiler warnings or StyleCop (Roslyn) warnings?

Answer (score 6):

Make a section in the `.editorconfig` file for that given class;
specify its file name `[{YourClass.cs}]` or path `[{Folder/YourClass.cs}]`in a section and set the `severity` for all rules to `none`.

See the `All rules` scope in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/configuration-options#scope).

```
[{YourClass.cs}]
dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.severity = none
```

Comment: I used this for my NativeFunctions.cs file. A better solution than the one by PMF as this doesn't abuse autogenerated XML-parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You can add this snippet at the very beginning of the file:

```
// <autogenerated />
```

This suppresses most warnings on that file.

Answer (score 0):

Use #pragma warning ( push ), then #pragma warning ( disable ), then put your code, then use #pragma warning ( pop ) as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/warning?view=msvc-170):

Replace warningCode below with the real codes

```
 #pragma warning( push )
 #pragma warning( disable : WarningCode)
 //code with warning
 #pragma warning( pop )
```